# Fourier transform of product measure

Tags: fourier-analysis

If $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are measures, how does the Fourier transform of $\mu_1 \times \mu_2$ compare to $\hat{\mu}_1$ and $\hat{\mu}_2$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\phi$ be the Fourier transform of $\mu_1\times \mu_2$. We can compute $\phi$ from the definition of the Fourier transform, using Fubini's theorem:
$$
\phi(\xi_1,\xi_2) = \int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{2\pi i x\cdot \xi} \,dx_1\,dx_2 
= \int_{\mathbb R} e^{2\pi i x_1 \xi_1} \,dx_1 \cdot \int_{\mathbb R} e^{2\pi i x_2 \xi_2} \,dx_2 = \hat \mu_1(\xi_1)\hat \mu_2(\xi_2)
$$
Your convention regarding $2\pi$ in the exponent may vary, but the relation stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Define [convolution of measures](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/computing-convolutions-of-measures/); try to see how it related to  $\mu_{1}\times \mu_{2}$; and  it is well-known that, $\widehat{\mu_{1}\ast \mu_{1}}=\hat{\mu_{1}}\hat{\mu_{2}}.$